# TextView Resize according to Content

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios9

A view there is inside textview. fixed at bottom of table. My concern is that when keyboard show view move upward according to his content. and key board hide they hide according his content.There occur some problem . It move more upward and then when we start write on textview they move downward. Please Help if its not solve my company fire me I am requesting you Please help. Here is my Code.

```
    - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
    {
        CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
        CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
        CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
        textView.frame = newFrame;
        CGRect frame1 = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
        bottomView.frame=CGRectMake(0, frame1.size.height-keyBoadSize-newSize.height-25, self.view.frame.size.width, newSize.height+25);

    }


- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
      NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    keyBoadSize =kbSize.height;

    CGRect keyboardRect = [aNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

               if (text.text.length ==0 ]) {
                    bottomView.frame =CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -kbSize.height-60, bottomView.frame.size.width, 60);
               }
               else
               {

               bottomView.frame =CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -kbSize.height-bottomView.frame.size.height, bottomView.frame.size.width, 60);
               }



           [tableViews setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0)];


    }];

}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{


    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    keyBoardDownHeight =kbSize.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
                   if (text.text.length ==0) {
                           bottomView.frame =CGRectMake(0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 60 , bottomView.frame.size.width, bottomView.frame.size.height);
            }
            else
            {
                 bottomView.frame =CGRectMake(0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -bottomView.frame.size.height-10 , bottomView.frame.size.width, bottomView.frame.size.height);
            }


        [tableViews setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

    }];


}
```

Comment: use this method [tableViews setContentOffset:<#(CGPoint)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>]; instead of [tableViews setContentInset:<#(UIEdgeInsets)#>];

Comment: My problem with bottom view.

Comment: Is bottom view in tableview?

Comment: not outside tableview

Comment: for the functionality as you said…you need to add tableview and bottom view in scrollview… and then use method setContentOffset: animated: (scrollview’s method) to scroll up and down according to keyboard behaviour…

Answer (score 0):

Make that your view or table view inherit from [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) classes and your issue will be resolved.

**Advice:** :The job of developer needs resistance against pressure ... never panic and work hard.